# PictureBox Layout issue in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am sure that my question or problem is really strange but this is it:

I am writing a program in c# which has a right to left layout (Arabic language). I am then adding the `pictureBox` control to be a background image in the form. I have set the dock of the `pictureBox` to be fill so it will be all the form.

Since the picture has some design that involves more than one color, I want to make the label transparent so that it does not have any color and it will take the color from the `pictureBox` itself. Here is how I make the label transparent:

```
label_customer_name.Parent = pictureBox1;

label_customer_name.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

This method works fine to change the color to transparent but there is a problem. When I set the parent of the label to be the `pictureBox`, the location of it changes and gets reflected on the other side. For example, if the location is set to be X after the execution, the location will be the form width - x. Any idea how to get rid of this problem?

What I am looking for in brief is:

1. Is there any other way to make the label transparent without setting the parent to the container control? Or
2. How to change the layout of `PictureBox` and force it to be from left to right.

Just as hint and the funny thing is that: if I add the `pictureBox` to a tab control and set the tab control to be right to left, the problem disappears as it seems that the `pictureBox` will get the layout from the tab control but it does not get it from the form itself.

Comment: Maybe you can use `form.BackgroundImage` instead of pictureBox (no idea if it will helps with label, as it seems to me what when you add label programmatically you also have to deal with `Anchor`, no idea how it works with RTL).

Comment: Dear bro, Thank you for your comment. I tried that solution but the problem is that when increasing the forum size the picture does not show well? Do you have any idea how to fix that.

Comment: What about place it into a panel ? If the tab control solve your problem, an invisible easy fix should be possible with a panel.

Comment: Dear bro, the panel has the right to left property but it does not have the right to left layout where you can change it. Tap control has both right to left and right to left layout properties.

Comment: Which version of .NET Framework are you using?

Comment: Dear bro, I am using Visual studio 2012

Comment: Check this question/answer ; look like your problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147657/how-to-make-righttoleftlayout-work-for-controls-inside-groupboxes-and-panels

Comment: Dear bro, This is related to other content in the form. I am asking either about the transparent label without the parent or forcing the pictureBox ti have right to left layout.

Comment: You could try wrapping the label with a RTLLabel usercontrol, which will have normal layout, and hold inside it the RTL label with auto-size set to true (GrowAndShrink), so you won't have any problems using the control with regular layout.

Comment: If my answer is useful please Accept that.

Answer (score 2):

Using GDI+ for Drawing Images with Transparency.

see this .

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25048/How-to-Use-Transparent-Images-and-Labels-in-Window

Good luck

Comment: If this is the best answer, click on the checkmark to mark it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `FlowLayoutPanel` control, that will serve for the hidden requirement, You can set `FlowDirection = RightToLeft` and `RightToLeft = True`.
Put the BackgroundImage of the panel to your image and add the labels to that panel.

Give it a try it should work.

Answer (score 0):

if your location changes after assigning the parent, you can keep the current location of label say (x,y) and assign a parent to it and then again set its location to (x,y)

ALSO You can try adding your label control into the picture box to set parent in different way.

```
pictureBox1.Controls.Add(label_customer_name);
```

One more solution for making your label control transparent is to set the label control's background similar to your picture box background. You can assign color that is in the background. (This is a dirty solution and i personally will not suggest this.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
Image im = Image.FromFile("imagePath");
this.BackgroundImage = im;
this.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
this.DoubleBuffered = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

The Label control become a child of the Form when using the Form Designer.
It's the cause of opaque. We need to set Parent property to the PictureBox
object after InitializeComponent.

```
InitializeComponent();
label1.Parent = pictureBox1;
label1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```