# RightToLeftLayout in Panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows project (C#) which we are going to use for Arabia. As we know the country following Right to Left mechanism. How can i move my all controls position in panel in RTL(Right to left) format. I have set properties 'RightToLeft' and 'RightToLeftLayout' to true but it moves controls inside the form only not panel. See the example

[image]

I had applied said properties when controls moved which are simply on the form, but controls inside panel, remain as is.

Comment: Please show Us where are You initializing and Setting these Property?

Comment: This might help? [How to: Display Right-to-Left Text in Windows Forms for Globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d3337xw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @ShekharPankaj at design time

Comment: @Izzy i did follow same but its not appliying inside panel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use this control :)

```
class MyPanel:Panel
{
    private bool myRightToLeftLayout=false;
    public bool MyRightToLeftLayout
    {
        get { return myRightToLeftLayout; }
        set 
        {
            if (value != myRightToLeftLayout)
            {
                foreach (Control item in base.Controls)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        item.RightToLeft = value==true?RightToLeft.No:RightToLeft.Yes;
                        item.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(base.Size.Width - item.Size.Width - item.Location.X, item.Location.Y);
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
                myRightToLeftLayout = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the result like this

`MyRightToLeftLayout = false`

[image]

`MyRightToLeftLayout = true`

[image]

Comment: thanx for your ans :) just wanted to know, should i sepratly add class of Panel ?

Comment: create a `class library` from this and then, you can use this `MyPanel` same as `Panel`

Comment: I tried and its working awesome. Thanks ... Sorry for late as i had to put some effort to implementation.

Comment: Your code is very clumsy. Much easier:    
item.Left = Width - item.Width - item.Left;

Answer (score 0):

Facts about RightToLeftLayout:

- It has effect if RightToLeft is set to Yes, only.
- RightToLeftLayout is a Boolean property and the values are true or false
  RightToLeftLayout property is not inherited by its child controls.
- Unlike the RightToLeft property you need to individually set the RightToLeftLayout to each individual control that supports this property.
- RightToLeftLayout would change the origin of its control and mirror the coordinates. So the origin is at the top-right instead of the top-left of the control. The coordinates would then increase to the left, instead of the right.

so according to second point you need to set it to all individual child elements

Comment: thanx for such a great explanation. So i have to move control manualy inside panel to display RTL . Right ?

Comment: no ..just loop across each and every child controls and set the properties instead

Comment: by doing this only text will be from RTL . My control ll not move right ?

Comment: yes. Only text getting RTL but i need to do this control in panel also

Answer (score -2):

You can do two of the things :

Firstly, in `Web.config` file of the web application, set the culture attribute of the `<globalisation>` element to 'ar-SA'

Secondly, Set the HTML dir attribute for the  element of each page to"rtl"

Comment: OP is talking about winforms

Comment: @Khan How will i set HTML dir and Web.config. I am using winForms

Comment: ohh..my bad..i didnt know that..I am not sure as i haven't worked in winForms.