# RightToLeftLayout in nested Panel

Tags: c#

Previously I asked query w.r.t. right to left layout in  panel [RightToLeftLayout in Panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26096550/righttoleftlayout-in-panel/26097090#26097090) but now I want to do the same for a nested panel (panel within panel).

When I try this

```
  class MyPanel:Panel 
  {
    private bool myRightToLeftLayout=false;
    public bool MyRightToLeftLayout
    {
        get { return myRightToLeftLayout; }
        set 
        {
            if (value != myRightToLeftLayout)
            {
                foreach (Control item in base.Controls)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        item.RightToLeft = value==true?RightToLeft.No:RightToLeft.Yes;
                        item.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(base.Size.Width - item.Size.Width - item.Location.X, item.Location.Y);
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
                myRightToLeftLayout = value;
            }
        }
    } 
  }
```

This behaves differently in a nested panel scenario (I know this code is described for only single panel).
How can I move if I am having nested panel (panel within panel) inside my form in a C# Windows application?

Comment: What do you mean by "this behaves diffrently in nested panel scenario" ?

Comment: means if i have nested panel and set myRightToLeftLayout to 'true' for both panel, than most front panel control goes out of panel