# Change application layout Right to Left

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I have an windows application developed in C#.NET. We have to deliver this application in country where language is Right-To-Left (Arabic).

Is there any way where I can write code to detect Locale and according to that Layout get changed. Means If there is an `panel` containing Label at left side and textBox at Right side then in Arabic (ar) Locale it get changed to TextBox at left side and Label at Right Side.

Comment: Don't write any code at all.  Set the form's Localizable property to True, change Language.

Comment: @HansPassant, I tired setting `Localizable` to true and `Language` property to Arabic(Egypt), Nothing happens all controls remains as it is i.e Left to Right.

Comment: Chang the right-to-left properties.  Now switch back to the default language.  And back again a Arabic.  Notice how the layout automatically changes when the language changes.

Comment: You want to change control's RightToLeft property. Do you want to change position of controls on winform also?

Comment: @UğurAldanmaz, Change position of controls also...

Comment: @HansPassant, I tried as you said, but doing this way make changes on form only. controls on panel remains as it is, I have some buttons,labels,textbox on panel

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147657/how-to-make-righttoleftlayout-work-for-controls-inside-groupboxes-and-panels

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this out of the box.So a little bit of code must be written.That means for instance that you can create custom controls that inherit from the control you are using,say Panel.

```
public class MyPanel:Panel
{
    public void SetLayoutToArabic()
    {
        foreach (Control oneChildControl in this.Controls)
        {
            //DO YOUR CHANGES        
        }
    }
}
```